# SQL Server : Select into same table?

Tags: sql-server, select

In SQL Server 2008 I have two tables. One table for users:

```
id_user - integer, primary key 
id_group - integer 
username - varchar 
phone - varchar 
id_coordinating - int
```

Sample data:

```
1, 1, admin,       0230029921, NULL 
2, 2, supervisor1, 0230029933, NULL
3, 2, supervisor2, 0321211233, NULL 
4, 3, user1,       0321222323, 2 
5, 3, user2,       0323211232, 2 
6, 3, user3,       0324223121, 3
```

All users in group USERS have one supervisor represented by the `id_user`

And another table for groups

```
id_group - integer, primary key 
groupname - varchar
```

Sample data:

```
1, Administrators 
2, Supervisors 
3, Users
```

I'm running the the following query:

```
select  id_user, username,  group.groupname, phone, id_coordinating
from users  
INNER JOIN group ON users.id_group = group.id_group
```

and I get the following result:

```
1 1 admin        Administrators 0230029921 NULL
2 2 supervisor1  Supervisors    0230029933 NULL
3 2 supervisor2  Supervisors    0321211233 NULL 
4 3 user1        Users          0321222323 2
5 3 user2        Users          0323211232 2 
6 3 user3        Users          0324223121 3
```

I want to replace the `id_coordonating` with the username and look like this...

```
1 1 admin        Administrators 0230029921 NULL 
2 2 supervisor1  Supervisors    0230029933 NULL 
3 2 supervisor2  Supervisors    0321211233 NULL 
4 3 user1        Users          0321222323 supervisor1  
5 3 user2        Users          0323211232 supervisor1  
6 3 user3        Users          0324223121 supervisor2
```

Thanks,

Comment: please format this question to make it more legible

Comment: @Scott that is the point of stackoverflow, you can edit and fix the highlighting to meet your needs.

Comment: @JonH It is also the responsibility of the asker to learn to format their questions properly.

Comment: @JonH I know this. I am on my iPhone and that would pose too much of a task for me. When I post a question, it is my responsibility to make my question as legible as possible so the answerers are clear on what I'm portraying.  I don't think it's too much to ask that others do the same. =D

Comment: @Scott Just saying that is all.  Don't know if you are on an iphone, a tablet, or any other device.  If we see a question that is poorly worded or not legible the point is we have the right to edit it.

Comment: @Jeff - Be patient - this person is new to the stackexchange community.  New things take time.

Comment: @JonH And when I am at my PC, I do just that. I just don't think you need to knock a comment that requests the asker to format their question.  No worries though. I'm not mad at ya. It looks good now thanks to you. =D

Comment: @Scott - not knocking anyone why did you assume that?

Comment: @JonH Agreed! :)  I was simply agreeing with Scott when he asked for the asker to improve the format of the question for legibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `left join` back onto your users table for this.

```
select
  u.id_user, 
  u.username,  
  g.groupname, 
  u.phone,
  u2.username
from users u
join group g
  on u.id_group = g.id_group
left join users u2
  on u.id_coordinating = u2.id_user
```